# Azure Speech to text demo through error.

Tags: azure, azure-speech

I am trying to run Azure speech ([Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript)) after running the app it through error.

> ConnectionEstablishErrorEvent and status code 1006

Followings are the error.

```
ConsoleLoggingListener.ts:29 2018-08-07T03:52:33.658Z | ConnectionEstablishErrorEvent | metadata: {} | connectionId: 68F4545775A842C294749791915B20D0 | statusCode: 1006 | reason: 
ConsoleLoggingListener.OnEvent @ ConsoleLoggingListener.ts:29
EventSource.OnEvent @ EventSource.ts:36
WebsocketMessageAdapter.OnEvent @ WebsocketMessageAdapter.ts:246
_this.websocketClient.onclose @ WebsocketMessageAdapter.ts:107
```

For better understanding, I am putting steps how I am running the project.

1. npm run bundle
2. cd samples/browser/
3. echo YOUR_BING_SPEECH_API_KEY > speech.key
4. npm install
5. node sample-server.js enableTunnel

Step 3 to 5 is already in README file. 
5th steps give the tunnel URL to run the application.
And after clicking and uploading an audio file it through the error which is visible in the web console.

Comment: did you figure this out by now?

Comment: No didn't just removed azure from our use, I thought someone from #azure will respond, as their documents say to ask a question on StackOverflow.